# BeautifulSoup 4 doesn't grab any element from the website

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used the following code to grab data from a website. It doesn't grab any element from the website.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url='website name'
uclient=ureq(my_url)
page_html=uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup=soup(page_html,"html.parser")
containers=page_soup.find_all("divs",{"class":"item-container"})
len(containers)
```

The length of containers shows 0. Please help.

Comment: website link: https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&ignorear=0&N=-1&isNodeId=1

Answer (score 0):

The tag name should be `div` not `divs`:

```
>>> len(page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'item-container'}))
12
```